# Syzygies of determinantal varieties: Looking for English text

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, syzygies, determinantal-ideals

I would like to understand the syzygies of the determinantal ideal $I_r$, generated by the $r\times r$ minors of a matrix $(X_{ij})$ of indeterminantes in the polynomial ring over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. The original resource for this object of study is the paper *"Syzygies des variétés déterminantales"* by Alain Lascoux [L]. While I would like to read it at some point, my rusty French is making it a bit cumbersome, and hence I was wondering if there were any translations of this treatment in English, possibly in some textbook. Thanks a lot in advance already.

**[L]** A. Lascoux, *Syzygies des variétés déterminantales*, Adv. Math. 30 (1978), 202–237.

     Mathematical Reviews (MathSciNet): [MR520233](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=520233)

     Digital Object Identifier: [doi:10.1016/0001-8708(78)90037-3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90037-3)

Comment: Is the Bruns-Vetter book ( http://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/wbruns/brunsw/detrings.pdf ) of any relevance?

Comment: Bruns-Vetter only treats special cases of the syzygies of determinantal ideals. At the end of Chapter 2 they mention Lascoux's work and ask whether a minimal free resolution exists in general over the integers. The answer is no: Hashimoto (in "Determinantal ideals without minimal free resolutions") showed that in characteristic 3, the Betti numbers change for the $2 \times 2$ minors of a $5 \times 5$ matrix (this example can also be seen in Macaulay2 now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weyman's book is a good reference. If you want other references, you can see the paper by myself joint with Snowden and Weyman: http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.3509

One can view the coordinate ring of the determinantal variety as a ring of invariants for a natural group action and in that paper we calculate the syzygies of all modules of covariants (see Section 1.6).

Answer (score 1):

A less sophisticated search was more successful. It's all there in Chapter 6 of the book **Cohomology of Vector Bundles and Syzygies** by Weyman.

Since I can't accept my own answer for another two days, feel free to post any other suggestions, though. More reading material can't hurt.

Comment: You have the right reference.  Lascoux's paper isn't a complete solution; he has to assume some constants he constructs are nonzero, but does not prove that the constants actually are nonzero.  (This is acknowledged in the paper; it was the best that could be done at the time.)  The paper that finishes off this problem in characteristic zero is by Pragacz and Weyman in the late 80s; I don't have the reference offhand but you'll find it in Weyman's book.

Answer (score 1):

For a bit different angle on this problem look at the review article "Diagrams of Hermitian type, highest weight modules, and syzygies of determinantal varieties" by Hunziker & al.

(Available at https://bearspace.baylor.edu/Markus_Hunziker/www/research.htm)